# solr query with white space and wildcar character

Tags: solr

I've got solr field with name 'allnames' - type string  which values are something like 'JOHN SMITH' and so on.

When i write this query with wildcard

`q=allnames:JO*`

it works ok and i've got as response what i want JOHN SMITH, JONATHAN LENORD  and so on

But if I write

`q=allnames:JOHN S*`

I've got zero results. Where may be the problem

Comment: What does your fieldtype definition for `allnames` look like? Do you have a WhiteSpaceTokenizer included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape special characters in SOlr queries.

[Here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters) is the Lucene definition of special characters.

Try your search with

```
q=allnames:JOHN\ S*
```

Note the backslash before the space.

Comment: Try logging the queries fired to Solr and look at the URL. My guess is that in the concat logic, somewhere the string isn't getting escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Just handle the space in your query.
Use this:

```
q=allnames:JOHN\ S*
```

Instead of:

```
q=allnames:JOHN S*
```